# Django can't find URL pattern

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I can't figure out why Django is unable to find the requested URL in my application.

Here is the error code I get:

```
 Using the URLconf defined in littlelogsms.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^admin/
^$
The current URL, success/, didn't match any of these.
```

Here is my **sms.urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from sms import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

Here is the application **urls.py** file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', include('sms.urls')),
]
```

I can't find the mistake I'm making. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This problem is the dollar sign in this url pattern.

```
url(r'^$', include('sms.urls')),
```

The caret `^` matches the beginning of the string, and the dollar `$` matches the end if the string, so `^$` only matches the index URL `/`.

You should remove the dollar and change it to:

```
url(r'^', include('sms.urls')),
```

Comment: thank you!! knew it was something very simple that I wasn't getting :)

Answer (score 1):

you should try with the base url,like

Here is the application urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^sms', include('sms.urls')),   # 'sms' is your defined name
]
```

Here is my sms.urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from sms import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^success/$', views.success, name='success'),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

you should try accessing your url's like in your views as

sms/    //for accessing tht index function in view
sms/success   //for accessing the success function in view

or you can use the labels in the form's action tag in the templates to call the urls,

{% url 'sms:index or success' %}   //index,success is the name space given in the sms.urls